# React: Inline if doesn't resolve to false when value is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

First of all, considering that the question seems quite obvious did a fair amount of research to find the answer but unfortunately I couldn't. Apologies in advance if this has been asked previously.

I'm currently learning React+Redux and have a pretty simple piece of code:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('user')); //undefined
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      localStorage.getItem('user') ?
        <Component {...props} /> :
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
    )} />
  )
}
```

When this code is executed, I'm expected that non-authenticated user will be redirected to the *login* page. However, for some reason, the inline `if` check for the `localStorage.getItem('user')` which resolves to `undefined` does not provide the expected result.

In addition, I've also tried `!!localStorage.getItem('user')` which also doesn't resolve to false and do not redirect to the page expected.

However, `localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined'` works like a charm.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

EDIT:

Condition `localStorage.getItem('user') === undefined` works fine, but why `localStorage.getItem('user')` doesn't resolve to a *falsy* `if` result itself?

localStorage contents:

```
Storage {darkyMode: "1", darkyState: "f", user: "undefined", darkySupported: "t", length: 4}
length: 4
darkyMode: "1"
darkyState: "f"
user: "undefined"
darkySupported: "t"
__proto__: Storage
```

FINAL EDIT:

So before adding the code to plunker to be reviewed by you guys I've added some more logging into my app to ensure I'm definitely not missing something obvious and as always, there was something obvious...

I had this piece of code in my userService:

```
return axios.post(`${api}/users/login`, {email, password})
    .then(res => onSuccess(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    .finally(user => localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
```

I don't know why I thought this was a good idea... Basically, every time user was not recognised, I was returning `message` property instead of `user` from the API and this resulted in `undefined` being set in the `localStorage`.

Previously, in the `onSuccess` method, I was only returning the data, now I am performing additional checks on the data and acting accordingly so moving `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))` from `.finally` into `onSuccess` method resolved the issue.

Marking @Christian Fritz answer as correct.

Thanks all for the help! :)

Comment: `'undefined' !== undefined`. One is a truthy string, the other, the real falsy `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe dumb question, but is `localStorage.getItem('user')` undefined, or is `localStorage` itself undefined in your code block?

Comment: @NicholasHirras if `localStorage` was undefined, OP's code would fail with _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined"_.

Comment: Ah thanks, next thought was looking at the docs, localStorage.getItem(...) should return null not undefined if the key didn't exist.

Comment: It just means that for some reason, OP set `user` to `undefined` in the localStorage, so the key exists, but once serialized, `undefined` becomes the string `'undefined'`.

Comment: In your latest edit, you're contradicting yourself. Please include a [mcve] (React is not even needed).

Comment: @EmileBergeron Sorry if I misunderstand your request but where am I contradicting myself? I've added another example, where strict equality check on `undefined` (non-string) works fine which means that the value of localStorage key actually resolves to it or I'm missing something again?

Comment: You're logging the storage which specifically shows `user: "undefined"` as a string value. So something isn't right in your example, which prevents us from helping further.

Comment: Also, depending on where and when you're logging, maybe it's really `undefined` at first, but elsewhere it gets set to `"undefined"` as a string, which we can't guess with the current snippet you've shared. Hence why a [mcve] is important.

Comment: I just did a code search for any files where I could set the 'user' to anything but no results. I'm not sure if that's right adding all the code in the post so I'll clean up the current very very in progress code and add a link to jsFiddle.

Comment: You're probably not setting it explicitly, but rather in an automated manner, like while saving the state with something like `localStorage.setItem(key, state[key])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the danger of stating the obvious, your storage contains `user: "undefined"`, i.e., a string, so yes, of course, `localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined'` will work and `!localStorage.getItem('user')` won't.

I suspect that you are testing for the logged-out case wrong. Make sure to use

```
localStorage.removeItem('user');
```

and *not* `localStorage.setItem('user', undefined)`. It's easy to test that this doesn't work the way one might expect:

```
> localStorage.setItem('user', undefined)
undefined
> localStorage.getItem('user')
"undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your localStorage, there is `user` key with value `undefined` which is a string. Given this is the case, you'd have to use `localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined'` as `'undefined'` doesn't resolve as `false`. The other way is you can [removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) when starting the application / user logs out